# mysqli database class not working?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am recently moved from mysql to mysqli but ,even after  lot of googling, facing problems. Plz review this database class and plz help me to find out,where I am wrong.Thanks.

I just altered the mysql to mysqli but it is not working.

```
<?php
class database {

  private $connection;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->connect();
  }

  public function connect() {
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'new5');
  }

}

$db = new database;
?>
```

In the other class, after including the above class, I am using `$db` as

```
class pro{

  $query = mysqli_query("SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM categories");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    echo $id

         }
     }
  }

$p = new pro();
```

I tried both ways, in mysqli procedural and OO way, but failed. Please suggest in both procedural and oop style.

Thanks

Comment: Is `$mysqli_query("..");` a typo? Hence the `$` before `mysqli_query` and your `class pro` doesn't make sense at all, the code between `class pro {` and `}` should be in a method, something like `public function queryCategories()`

Comment: Where are you creating the object of database class in pro class ?

Comment: @ShubhanshuMishra ,this class just works fine when using mysql.

Comment: @SidraNaeem It's not about getting it to work with _mysql_ but with _mysqli_ is it not? It's a good question, though you said you included this class before executing `$p=new pro();` so I'm assuming `mysqli_connect()` is creating a valid resource link to the mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, if `$mysqli_query` is not a typo, remove the `$`.

Also the `while` statement is missing an ending curly bracket `}`.

Second, your `class pro { .. }` definition does not make sense. The code between the curly brackets should be placed in a method, I suggest naming it something like `queryCategories`.

```
class pro {
  public function queryCategories() {
    $query=msqli_query("SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM categories");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
      $id=$row["id"];
      echo $id
    } // ending while curly bracket was failing
  }
}

$p = new pro();
$p->queryCategories();
```

Comment: ,thanks,but it giving the error as Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given i

Comment: @SidraNaeem No offence, but you should do a bit more research, it means mysqli_query did not return a valid resource, e.g. No database connection etc, check the content of $db and the property $connection if anything even remotely points to a valid database connection